# Qt test if file is a device

Tags: qt, file, winapi, posix

I have a file name string of a serial device. It can be a Windows COM port, or a UNIX `/dev/` character device file.

So I am looking for something like:

```
bool isCharDevice(QString name) {
    // something like
    return QFileInfo(name).isSomething();
    // or
    return QFile(name).isSomething();
}
```

I am after the same thing, which I would do in unix shell with `test -c $name`, or from C code with [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) (code snippet for reference below). But I want it to also work on Windows, and I would prefer a plain Qt solution. I did not find an answer in [QFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfile.html) and [QFileInfo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfileinfo.html) documentation.

Is this possible with plain Qt?

If not, and I need to go down the `#ifdef` route, how to test the approximately same thing (verify that file name refers to something which could be a serial port) in Windows?

---

For reference, the POSIX code snippet:

```
    struct stat st;
    stat(name_cstr, &st);
    if (S_ISCHR(st.st_mode)) {...}
```

---

**Update**: After more investigation, it seems the Windows COM ports are not accessible with `QFile` at all: `QFile("COM4:").exists()` will return false even if that COM port exists and command prompt command `type COM4:` works. So it seems what I ask is not possible with plain Qt at all on Windows, need to use a serial port library anyway.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [QIODevice::isSequential()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qiodevice.html#isSequential)?

Comment: @thuga That's good, didn't notice that method! However, just tested and noticed, that actually the special devices are not accessible with QFile in Windows at all, it seems. So feel free to convert that comment into a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As character devices usually do not support random access to data, you can try using [`QIODevice::isSequential()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qiodevice.html#isSequential).

Answer (score 1):

`QFileInfo(name).isFile()` returns false for non-regular files.